# read one line with "read" in bash, but without "while"

Tags: bash

I was trying to understand how "while read" works in bash, and i came accross a behaviour that i can't explain:

```
root@antec:/# var=old_value
root@antec:/# echo "new_value" | read var && echo $var
old_value
root@antec:/#
```

It works fine with "while read":

```
root@antec:/# var=old_value
root@antec:/# echo "new_value" | while read var; do echo $var; done
new_value
root@antec:/#
```

Can someone explain why it does not work when read is used without while ? Moreover, i don't understand how the value of "var" in the main shell can be seen from the allegedly subshell after the pipe ..

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is precedence problem, with | having higher precedence than &&.  First is grouped as:

```
(echo "new_value" | read var) && echo $var
```

Second is grouped as:

```
echo "new_value" | (while read var; do echo $var; done)
```

Comment: I would never have thought about that ! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Why do you think it works in the second case? It doesn't really update `var`. do `echo $var` after the line with `while` and see.

Explanation: whatever comes after `|` is executed in a subshell that has its own copy of `var`. The original `var` is not affected in either case. What is echoed depends on whether `echo` is called in the same subshell that does `read` or not.

Comment: The problem is not to update `var` in the main shell or not, maybe i was unclear in the question. I was interested in what is echoed, as you talk about in your last sentence :)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to print the variable immediately but use it later on and this works:

```
var=old_value
read var < <(echo "new_value")
echo $var
> new_value
```

alternatively:

```
var=old_value
tmp=$(echo "new_value")
read var <<<"$tmp"
echo $var
> new_value
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `while` loop:

```
echo "new_value" | (read var; echo $var)
```